# Apache Ambari install problem

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'm trying to install Ambari from Apache BigTop repo, but I'm getting error regarding python dependency:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo apt install ambari\*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ambari-server' for glob 'ambari*'
Note, selecting 'ambari-agent' for glob 'ambari*'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ambari-agent : Depends: python (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
 ambari-server : Depends: python (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Checking python:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3   2         manual mode
```

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `dpkg -l python2.7`? Do you have python installed from the Ubuntu repo? Because that's what `apt` will be looking for - the package  specifically - not the python binary in the path.

Comment: `vagrant@vagrant:~$ dpkg -l python2.7
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version            Architecture Description
+++-==============-==================-============-=============================================================
ii  python2.7      2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1 amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)`

Comment: Are you inside some kind of vagrant environment? Can you install the debs outside of that environment, if so?

Comment: Yes this is vagrant VM. I tried also installing VM using images directly from ubuntu, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem deploying Ambari (2.7.5) packaged by Bigtop (3.2.0) on Ubuntu 22.04.
The problem is that Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't has the `python (>= 2.6.0)` package. You must to use the `python2 (>= 2.7)` package insted.
To change this package, open file `bigtop-packages/src/deb/ambari/control` file in Bigtop Ambari project and change `python (>= 2.6.0)` to `python2 (>= 2.7)`.
This must be done in `bigtop-ambari-mpack` project too.
After that, rebuild your packages and pack they again before test a new deploy.
Remember that you could has problems with python incompatibilities between version `2.6` to `2.7`. I have not yet tested this issues.

The new `control` file will been like this:

```
Source: ambari
Section: misc
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Bigtop <dev@bigtop.apache.org>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 6)
Standards-Version: 3.8.0
Homepage: http://ambari.apache.org/

Package: ambari-server
Architecture: all
Depends: openssl, postgresql (>= 8.1), python2 (>= 2.7), curl
Description: Ambari Server 

Package: ambari-agent
Architecture: all
Depends: openssl, python2 (>= 2.7), curl
Description: Ambari Agent
```

Maybe the answer been late. But i hope that this could help others with this problem.